# How can put Resource in other component?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am using react-admin to create an admin panel.

I want to show Resource in another component, my component is Tab used to  Show in React-admin.

Code:

```
 <SimpleShowLayout>
  <TabbedShowLayout>
    <Tab label="Products">
      <Admin authProvider={authProvider} dataProvider={dataProvider}>
        <Resource name="products" {...products}/>
      </Admin>
    </Tab>
  </TabbedShowLayout>
</SimpleShowLayout>
```

how can I do it? Thanks

Comment: The question is unclear. What another component do you want to show Resource in?

Comment: For starters, you don't need that outer `<SimpleShowLayout>` you should be able to just use the one `<TabbedShowLayout>`

Comment: Can you please provide more information about what you want to show within the Products tab?